# What hardware should I use to mine MUE?

Tags: mining-profitability

Will I use video card? or PC? I plan to mine MUE and use the coin I mined to buy bitcoins.

This says MUE is the best

http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency/?sha256hr=9460.00&sha256p=2600.00&sha256pc=0.1000&sha256c=false&scrypthr=110000.00&scryptp=1000.00&scryptpc=0.1000&scryptc=true&x11hr=450.00&x11p=120.00&x11pc=0.1000&x11c=true&keccakhr=1000.00&keccakp=600.00&keccakpc=0.1000&keccakc=true&quarkhr=450000.00&quarkp=75.00&quarkpc=0.1000&quarkc=true&groestlhr=45.00&groestlp=825.00&groestlpc=0.1000&groestlc=true&blake256hr=11.20&blake256p=600.00&blake256pc=0.1000&blake256c=true&neoscrypthr=400.00&neoscryptp=400.00&neoscryptpc=0.1000&neoscryptc=true&lyra2rev2hr=30.00&lyra2rev2p=600.00&lyra2rev2pc=0.1000&lyra2rev2c=true&cryptonighthr=2800.00&cryptonightp=600.00&cryptonightpc=0.1000&cryptonightc=true&ethashhr=108.00&ethashp=600.00&ethashpc=0.1000&ethashc=true&equihashhr=1180.00&equihashp=600.00&equihashpc=0.1000&equihashc=true&e=CEX.io

However, it's not clear what hardware this one use. I can't find more info on MUE.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.coinwarz.com/cryptocurrency/coins/monetaryunit

Comment: Doesn't tell me what GPU I should buy to mine this thing.